# How to separate Crosswalk libxwalkcore.so into separate arm and x86 apk's

Tags: android, android-x86, crosswalk-runtime

I am using Crosswalk browser for my current application, and after the building process it creates 2 libraries (Which are around 17 mb in size each).

And since that adds a big amount of overhead to the application, i was trying to separate the build into 2 different apk's one for arm and one for x86 architecture.

According to android documentation it is possible, but I was not able to found enough information.

Is it possible to build two times with each time only one version of crosswalk lib getting added ?

Answer (score 1):

looking at crosswalk's [make_apk.py](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk/blob/master/app/tools/android/make_apk.py), it seems that by default, different APKs are already generated for each platform.

You can specify which architectures you want to generate an APK for using the `--arch` option that can be set to either `x86`, `x86_64` or `arm`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to manually delete libxwalkcore.so under crosswalk project -> libs -> armeabi-v7a or x86. 
Depending on for which architecture you wish to built delete the other .so file.